# Новогодний алгоритм 2018

Tags: поддержка, соревнование

Новый год и [алгоритм](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc) всегда приходят вместе: предлагаем вам принять участие в новогоднем конкурсе на лучшие вопросы и ответы по метке [алгоритм](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc)!

Правила просты – необходимо задавать вопросы и отвечать на них.

#### Условия подробно

В игре участвуют все вопросы, заданные с 1–го по 31–е января 2018 года с меткой [алгоритм](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc), а также ответы, данные за аналогичный период на вопросы по метке [алгоритм](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc)<sup>*</sup>.

*<sub>Учитывается время создания конкретного сообщения: если соответствующий критериям ответ будет опубликован на ранее заданный вопрос, он также будет учитываться при подсчете результатов.</sub>

#### Победители

Победителем будет считаться:

1. Автор вопроса с наибольшим рейтингом.
2. Автор ответа с наибольшим рейтингом.
3. Автор ответа на свой вопрос, если ответ получит больший рейтинг, чем любой другой ответ к этому же вопросу.
4. Автор принятого ответа с наибольшим рейтингом.
5. Автор вопроса, получившего наибольшее количество ответов.
6. Автор вопроса с наибольшим количеством просмотров.
7. Автор наибольшего количества вопросов.
8. Автор наибольшего количества ответов.

Среди всех сообщений, удовлетворяющих условию, выбирается одно — с наибольшим рейтингом или опубликованное ранее. «Зимние игры» пройдут в две сессии.

- *Первая сессия*: с 1–го января по 10–е января.
- *Вторая сессия*: с 11–го января по 31–е января.

В каждой сессии будут свои победители, но один приз вручается в одни руки. Таким образом, если вы станете лучшим в одной категории несколько раз или лучшим в нескольких категориях в одной сессии, приз будет все равно один. С другой стороны, за каждую победу в категории дается один «призовой балл». Лидеру общего зачета, то есть участнику, набравшему наибольшее количество призовых баллов, будет вручен секретный суперприз.

#### Призы

Истинным призом, конечно же, являются знания, и только ради них уже стоит принимать участие! В дополнение к знаниям и хорошему настроению победители получат на выбор футболки, блокноты, наклейки, термокружки или другие памятные призы!

Знаете того, кто может задать отличный вопрос по алгоритмам? Пожалуйста, предложите ему/ей принять участие!

С нетерпением ждем ваших вопросов с меткой [алгоритм](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc) (не забудьте подписаться на нее, чтобы не пропустить новые вопросы)!

**Важно**: Подсчет результатов будет осуществляться по прошествии 10 дней с момента окончания соревновательной сессии, чтобы уровнять шансы получения голосов.

---

#### Запросы на выявление победителей

Победители будут определяться с помощью SQL–запросов на [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/).

Примеры запросов для выявления победителей.

1. Автор вопроса с наибольшим рейтингом.

   ```
   SELECT p.OwnerUserId, p.Id, p.Title, p.Score 
   From Posts p 
     Join PostTags t on t.PostId = p.Id 
   Where t.TagId = 38 AND p.PostTypeId = 1 AND p.CreationDate >= '2018-01-01' AND p.CreationDate < '2018-01-11' 
   ORDER BY p.Score desc;
   ```
2. Автор ответа с наибольшим рейтингом.

   ```
   SELECT p.OwnerUserId, p.Id, parent.Title, p.Score
   From Posts p 
     Join Posts parent on parent.Id = p.ParentId 
     Join PostTags t on t.PostId = parent.Id 
   Where t.TagId = 38 AND p.PostTypeId = 2 AND p.CreationDate >= '2018-01-01' AND p.CreationDate < '2018-01-11' 
   ORDER BY p.Score desc;
   ```
3. Автор ответа на свой вопрос, если ответ получит больший рейтинг, чем любой другой ответ к этому же вопросу (находит ответы на свои вопросы).

   ```
   SELECT p.OwnerUserId, p.Id, parent.Title, p.Score
   From Posts p 
     Join Posts parent on parent.Id = p.ParentId 
     Join PostTags t on t.PostId = parent.Id 
   Where t.TagId = 38 AND p.PostTypeId = 2 AND p.OwnerUserId = parent.OwnerUserId AND p.CreationDate >= '2018-01-01' AND p.CreationDate < '2018-01-11' 
   ORDER BY p.Score desc;
   ```
4. Автор принятого ответа с наибольшим рейтингом.

   ```
   SELECT p.OwnerUserId, p.Id, parent.Title, p.Score
   From Posts p 
     Join Posts parent on parent.Id = p.ParentId 
     Join PostTags t on t.PostId = parent.Id 
   Where t.TagId = 38 AND p.PostTypeId = 2 AND p.Id = parent.AcceptedAnswerId AND p.CreationDate >= '2018-01-01' AND p.CreationDate < '2018-01-11' 
   ORDER BY p.Score desc;
   ```
5. Автор вопроса, получившего наибольшее количество ответов.

   ```
   SELECT p.OwnerUserId, p.Id, p.Title, p.AnswerCount, p.Score  
   From Posts p 
     Join PostTags t on t.PostId = p.Id 
   Where t.TagId = 38 AND p.PostTypeId = 1 AND p.CreationDate >= '2018-01-01' AND p.CreationDate < '2018-01-11' 
   ORDER BY p.AnswerCount desc, p.Score desc;
   ```
6. Автор вопроса с наибольшим количеством просмотров.

   ```
   SELECT p.OwnerUserId, p.Id, p.Title, m.ViewCount, p.Score 
   From Posts p 
     Join PostTags t on t.PostId = p.Id 
     Join PostMetadata m on m.PostId = p.Id
   Where t.TagId = 38 AND p.PostTypeId = 1 AND p.CreationDate >= '2018-01-01' AND p.CreationDate < '2018-01-11' 
   ORDER BY m.ViewCount desc, p.Score desc;
   ```
7. Автор наибольшего количества вопросов.

   ```
   SELECT p.OwnerUserId, COUNT (DISTINCT p.Id) AS Number
   From Posts p 
     Join PostTags t on t.PostId = p.Id 
   Where t.TagId = 38 AND p.PostTypeId = 1 AND p.CreationDate >= '2018-01-01' AND p.CreationDate < '2018-01-11' 
   GROUP BY p.OwnerUserId
   ORDER BY Number desc;
   ```
8. Автор наибольшего количества ответов.

   ```
   SELECT p.OwnerUserId, COUNT(DISTINCT p.Id) AS Number
   From Posts p 
     Join Posts parent on parent.Id = p.ParentId 
     Join PostTags t on t.PostId = parent.Id 
   Where t.TagId = 38 AND p.PostTypeId = 2 AND p.CreationDate >= '2018-01-01' AND p.CreationDate < '2018-01-11' 
   GROUP BY p.OwnerUserId
   ORDER BY Number desc;
   ```

Comment: 1. А нельзя ли заменить sql-запросы на обращения к api, чтобы получать актуальные рейтинги, а не с задержкой на неделю? 2. Если уж SEDE, то можно было бы ссылочку на готовый запрос добавить.

Comment: Надо разморозить чат "Номинашки", ссылки на него у меня нету :(

Comment: @Qwertiy Да, думал об этом! Как только первый раз буду победителей выбирать, постараюсь заменить на ссылки. (Единственное, я все–таки по локальной базе выборку делать буду.)

Comment: @АндрейNOP, готово: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61455/

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, я ж два года назад что-то с аджаксом делал, но не через api

Comment: @Qwertiy, гуд :)

Comment: [`[алгоритм] created:01-01-2018..01-10-2018`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5B%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%5D+created%3A01-01-2018..01-10-2018)

Comment: Пора награждать за первую сессию

Comment: @АндрейNOP Так и есть! Чуть чуть анонс задерживается.

Comment: а призы?.......

Comment: @Anatol  Памятные сувениры будут вручены по завершению соревнований. Как только мы подведем итоги второй сессии, я свяжусь со всеми победителями по почте.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, а как Вы узнаете мою почту? Письма я не увидел =)

Comment: @ДаниилЧижевский У вас есть почта, привязанная к учетной записи в вашем профиле участника. Писал на нее.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, там нет(((

Comment: @ДаниилЧижевский Спасибо, что дали знать! Я обязательно проверю все и вышлю повторно!

Answer (score 6):

## Результаты первой сессии Новогоднего алгоритма 2018

От лица сообщества спешу поздравить победителей первой сессии! Большое спасибо вам и всем, принявшим участие в первой сессии «зимних игр»!

#### Автор вопроса с наибольшим рейтингом и автор вопроса, получившего наибольшее количество ответов

[@elena](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/280361/elena) с вопросом [Как отсортировать целые числа от 1 до n так, чтобы каждое число, начиная со второго, делило сумму чисел, стоящих левее него, нацело](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767979/). Вопрос получил 13 голосов за и 4 ответа.

#### Автор ответа с наибольшим рейтингом и aвтор принятого ответа с наибольшим рейтингом

[@Harry](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/195342/harry) с ответом на вопрос [Как отсортировать целые числа от 1 до n так, чтобы каждое число, начиная со второго, делило сумму чисел, стоящих левее него, нацело](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767979/). Ответ получил 10 голосов за и был отмечен как верный. Интересно, что в вопросе речь шла о Python, а ответ на C++ :)

#### Автор ответа на свой вопрос, если ответ получит больший рейтинг, чем любой другой ответ к этому же вопросу

[@Qwertiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178988/qwertiy) с ответом к своему вопросу [Как реализовать нормальные алгоритмы Маркова](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/768634/). Ответ получил два голоса за.

#### Автор вопроса с наибольшим количеством просмотров

[@tym32167](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/179763/tym32167) с вопросом [Сервис по реверсу MD5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/768072/). Вопрос набрал 331 просмотр к моменту составления отчета.

#### Автор наибольшего количества вопросов

[@Даниил Чижевский](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/228528/) задал три вопроса за время первой сессии «зимних игр». Вопросы в сумме получили 5 голоса за, один против и три ответа. Два вопроса значатся как отвеченные.

#### Автор наибольшего количества ответов

[@Harry](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/195342/harry) опубликовал за время первой сессии 7 ответов, которые набрали в сумме рейтинг +26!

---

Вторая сессия в самом разгаре! У каждого все еще есть возможность стать лидером второй сессии Новогоднего алгоритма 2018! Задавайте вопросы, публикуйте ответы с меткой [алгоритм](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc) и становитесь победителями!

Answer (score 3):

## Результаты второй сессии Новогоднего алгоритма 2018

От лица сообщества поздравляю победителей второй сессии! Большое спасибо вам и всем, принявшим участие «зимних играх»!

#### Автор вопроса с наибольшим рейтингом и автор вопроса с наибольшим количеством просмотров

[@yoloy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/280801/yoloy) с вопросом [Подсчет минимального возможного количества замен у числа "x" по заданному алгоритму: x=m*n; x=m+n-2, где m и n - какие-то натуральные числа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/770303/). Вопрос получил 10 голосов «за» и 3 ответа.

#### Автор ответа с наибольшим рейтингом и aвтор принятого ответа с наибольшим рейтингом

[@Harry](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/195342/harry) с ответом на вопрос [Подсчет минимального возможного количества замен у числа “x” по заданному алгоритму: x=m*n; x=m+n-2, где m и n - какие-то натуральные числа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/770528/6). Ответ получил 11 голосов за и был отмечен верным. Как ни странно, ситуация зеркально первой сессии: вопрос с меткой [tag-python], набравший максимум голосов, но ответ на [c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).

#### Автор ответа на свой вопрос, если ответ получит больший рейтинг, чем любой другой ответ к этому же вопросу

[@diraria](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/227016/diraria) с ответом на свой вопрос [Генерация сочетания k элементов из множества n](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/773073/6). Ответ получил 6 голосов за!

#### Автор вопроса, получившего наибольшее количество ответов

[@Anton](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/264297/anton) с вопросом [Как автоматически определить категорию слова](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/777591/), который получил 4 ответа.

#### Автор наибольшего количества вопросов

[@diraria](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/227016/diraria) задал четыре вопроса за время второй сессии «зимних игр». Вопросы в сумме получили 13 голоса за и пять ответов.

#### Автор наибольшего количества ответов

[@Harry](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/195342/harry) опубликовал за время второй сессии 12 ответов, которые набрали в сумме рейтинг +37!

### Сумма побед по итогам Игр

По сумме всех двух сессий лидером в суммарном зачет стал [@Harry](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/195342/harry)! Наши поздравления!

Comment: @ДаниилЧижевский Вам на почту должно было прийти письмо, в котором рассказывается, что необходимо сделать для получения памятного сувенира!